# IndexedDB transaction.oncomplete with multiple actions

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

The question is: how does an IDBTransaction -- the kind you get from IDBDatabase, we'll call it type A -- know when to call `oncomplete` if it can be include an arbitrary number of IDBTransaction (type B) children?

First, you get your 'type A' IDBTransaction from the database connection:

```
const transA = IDBDatabase.transaction(storeName, mode);
```

This IDBT may carry the `oncomplete` event, and supposedly it will fire when the *total* transaction is complete. But you use this IDBT to 'launch' the real transactions via one or more retrieved IDBObjectStores:

```
const store = transA.objectStore(storeName);
const transB1 = store.delete(key);
const transB2 = store.add(item);
```

Now, `transB1` and `transB2` are also instances of IDBTransaction, which may have their own `oncomplete` handlers. The idea of the parent transaction here, as I understand it, is that it permits the aggregate transaction to be atomic; if transB1 succeeds but transB2 fails, transB1 is rolled back. Good. So we'll generally be more interested in listening to the parent, not the children, since this is what tells us if it *really* succeeded.

The catch I don't get: there's no `close` or `done` or `finish` method or whatever. So how does `transA` actually know when to trigger `oncomplete`?

All I can think of at the moment is that it expects all child transactions to be created during a single tick. Is that what's going on? (It's already pretty apparent that IndexedDB is painfully un-JS, but quietly relying on synchrony to imply behavior like that seems like a boundary even the DOM overlords would not cross.) What's really going on?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own after some experimentation.

The answer, it turns out, seems to be yes, that's really just how it works. Reliance on synchrony is true across the board -- not as surprising once it clicks that these aren't "real" event handlers in the first place (e.g. `transaction.on('complete', ...)`) -- which means there's maybe no way at all to wrap indexedDB in an API that doesn't, to some extent, mirror its own horrific form. :(

(Not marking as accepted; maybe someone has more insight yet.)

Comment: You're mostly right for the time being. Some [creative interpretation of the current specs](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457409) might provide some respite. Although this is still up in the air, it does kind of work in at least some browsers and promise libraries today. And hopefully the situation will be better in the future - there are ideas like [this](https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/8c122c84a65de65c35b3) floating around.

Comment: Very informative links dumbmatter. The proposal addresses pretty much everything that had me scratching my head. In fact one of the first things I tried was to implement a half-assed async iterator over cursor because the way it's implemented felt utterly wrong.

Comment: Can you put codeblocks in comments?
`const cursGen = function * () {

  let cursor, resolved, resolve, reject;

  this.onsuccess = ({ target: { result } }) => {
    resolved = true;
    cursor = result;
    resolve(cursor && cursor.value);
  };

  this.onerror = this.onabort = err => {
    resolved = true;
    cursor = null;
    reject(err);
  };

  do {
    yield new Promise(($resolve, $reject) => {
      resolve  = $resolve;
      reject   = $reject;

      if (cursor) cursor.continue();
    });

    if (!resolved) throw new AsyncIteratorError();
    resolved = false;

  } while (cursor)
};`

Comment: (For context if you do bother to read that without whitespace, it gets bound to the IDBCursor, and then can be used in a regular for-of loop in an es7 async function -- `for (const cursor of req::cursGen()) { const document = await cursor; ... }`)

Answer (score 2):

The indexedDB API is designed to be autocommited. So when ever a transaction is getting idle it will be commited by default, so you don't need to do it manually like most SQL databases. This means the oncomplete callback will be called automatically when the transaction completes/ The only thing you can do manually is aborting the transaction.

Nested transaction like you want to have aren't possible in this API. Transactions are expected to be short-lived, so the browser can terminate a transaction that takes too long, in order to free up storage resources that the long-running transaction has locked.

Btw why should you need multiple transactions? You can do all the actions in a single transaction?

Comment: Multiple sub-transactions from the base transaction are a feature of indexedDB meant for atomic changes across multiple docs / collections. I don't really need this much at the moment, but I was seeking to write a generic layer over indexedDB and wanted to leave the door open. The overarching issue I was facing was that the same-tick constraint made creating a promise-returning API much more difficult. Promises are async by nature -- I could wrap .transaction() to abstract its hideous innards, but when the promise resolved, the consumer would no longer be able to place handlers on the result!

Comment: (cont) Despite what I said earlier, I've realized that creating a normal document DB API *is* possible (you just need to queue actions in a monad-like-thing, up to exec()), but you do need to jump through a lot of hoops to create such an interface, especially when cursors are involved.

Comment: I have written a library on top of the indexeddb API my self, called linq2indexedDB. This is an open-source project, so you can just look at my code :). I also used promises to on all the actions to make my life a bit easier :). For the transactions I used the progress callback to return the actieve transaction. In the progress callback of the transaction I executed all my actions. The resolved callback was called when the oncomplete was called on the transaction.

Comment: Thanks, looks very instructive and thorough, a good reference!